# Conflict in ES6 String Interpolation and jQuery $

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, ecmascript-6

**STUPID QUESTION : DON'T BOTHER**

I am newbie in ES6 and following this guide [here](http://www.2ality.com/2015/08/getting-started-es6.html) to get started. I looked at the following code and been thinking since then.

```
function printCoord(x, y) {
    console.log(`(${x}, ${y})`);
}
```

So we use `${VARIABLE}` to get it's value as string. Now if I were to use jQuery as **$** would it conflict with the above code? or jQuery would just ignore anything in between **``` `` ```** ?

Would we be able to do something like...

```
console.log(`(${ $('.selector').text() })`);
```

Would it require me to use jQuery as `jQuery` everywhere?

Comment: @Vohuman  so would i be able to do this `console.log(`(${ $('.selector').text() })`);` ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But why don't you test it? "jQuery would just ignore anything in between ``". jQuery is just a JavaScript library, it has no control on how JavaScript interpreter works.

Comment: I am just trying to test on babel/repl. I'll be back shortly.

Comment: Yep that works! thanks! I tried babel locally and ran.

Comment: What made you think that `$` would conflict with jQuery? It doesn't conflict in string literals (`'$("foo")'`) or regex literals (`/foo$/`) either. The `$` inside the template literal is just a special character (together with the `{}`), it's not evaluated as a variable.

Comment: Now that i think of it it's really a stupid question. I should have really thought more. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a jsfiddle. (Added jQuery, babel as language)

http://jsfiddle.net/kamikazefish/hd1Le21z/

```
<div class="selector">This is the text in the selector</div>

console.log(`(${ $('.selector').text() })`);
alert(`(${ $('.selector').text() })`);
```

Seems like it works.